# position absolute is collapsing

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div id="Science" class="subjectsParent">
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Science
        </div>
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Science
        </div>
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Science
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Sports" class="subjectsParent">
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Sports
        </div>
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Sports
        </div>
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Sports
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Physics" class="subjectsParent">
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Physics
        </div>
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Physics
        </div>
        <div class="subject" draggable="true">
            Physics
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.subject {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.subjectsParent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

All the divs are collapsing altogether.

See here https://jsfiddle.net/a1quymqe/3/

What I want is only the same subjects should collapse together in there "subjectsParent" class.

**Result I want:**

[image]

(2 more same div behind these divs)

Comment: try and create an image representation of what you want, im finding it hard to grasp exactly what you want here

Comment: How exactly you want it to look

Comment: I've the added Image.

Comment: Why do you have a lot of element? Is it not achievable using single element per subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to give the last child position relative. This works no matter how many divs you use.

```
.subject {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}
.subject:last-child {
    position: relative;
}

.subjectsParent {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avvwa75h/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
.subject {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.subjectsParent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

//first two can be absolute    
.subjectsParent .subject:first-child,.subjectsParent .subject:nth-child(2){
  position: absolute;
}
```

[working JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/w1ayjrvx/)

Comment: Of course. Position relative to the parent. +1 for beating me to it!

Comment: number of divs can be increased.

Comment: No need to increase divs. Isn't the solution you want?

Comment: In real I want it upto 32 divs. you have used first and second child. How I can change it to use it more times? make it more dynamic?

Comment: reverse the logic as JoostS says.. basically keep all children absolute and make first or last or any child relative in position.